# Finding by latest value of a column along with other predicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a schema as following:

```
Products(name, company_id, version)
```

Adding some dummy data:

| name | company_id | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| c | 2 | 1 |
| a | 2 | 1 |

I want to find all the rows which have `name=a`, `company_id=1` and the version is latest.

I looked at [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column) and build a query as following

```
SELECT * FROM Products p
WHERE p.name = a AND p.company_id = 2 AND p.version =
    (SELECT MAX(q.version) FROM Products q 
    WHERE q.name = a AND q.company_id = 2)
```

Is there any better way in which these type of queries can be designed? I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TOP`, we can try:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Products
WHERE name = 'a' AND company_id = 1
ORDER BY version DESC;
```

A generalization to get the most recent version for every company in the table:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM Products
WHERE name = 'a'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY version DESC);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can this be generalized to return all the latest products filtered by `company_id`?

Comment: @JavaLearner Yes, you can use a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick, with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the query but now that I understand it, it's beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 P.*
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
WHERE P.name = 'A' AND P.company_id = 2
ORDER BY P.version DESC
```

I guess, you can try this